# Dlookup/rank next 3 field's after today's date

Tags: ms-access, expression

Part of my database form that I created will list the newest added event as well as the next upcoming 3 events that we are hosting. However I am unable to figure out how to get the dlookup expression to return the correct values into the form field.

I use the following expression to return the latest event added:

```
=DLookup("[Event Name]","[Events]","[Event Date] = DMax('[Event Date]','[Events]')")
```

Which works perfectly well for that field, moving onto the upcoming events, I was looking for an expression that lists the next 3 events

I use the below to list the next event

```
=DLookUp("[Event Name]","[Events]","[Event Date] >= now()")
```

This again works fine however the problem occurs when trying to list event #2 & #3. I was wondering if possible to use the dlookup expression / rewrite the expression to list the next 2 upcoming events.

I also created a [new query](https://imgur.com/8k4XR5t) to list all events after now() and was thinking of using DCount and referring to that instead with a mod however I can't find the right criteria

```
=DCount("  [View - Upcoming Events]![Event Name] "," [View - Upcoming Events]","[Event Name] <= & [Event Name]") Mod 2

=DCount("  [View - Upcoming Events]![Event Name] "," [View - Upcoming Events] "," [Event Name] <= " & [Event Name]) Mod 2
```

This will always return #Name or #Error depending on how I play around with the coding. And I've misplaced my big list of expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your (secret) query, insert a **TOP 3** statement to select only the *three top records*, like:

```
Select TOP 3 [Event Name], [Event Date] 
From [Events]
Where [Event Date] > Date()
Order By [Event Date] Asc
```

Comment: Fantastic, that narrowed down the top 3 easier than pulling all events which allowed me to create a subform to display this! Perfect